# Trigger Power Automate flow from SharePoint list item

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I am trying to trigger at Power Automate flow, from at Modern SharePoint list element.
By default this is pretty straight forward, as these two links also show.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Hp9CTd8zQU

https://michalguzowski.pl/how-to-trigger-microsoft-flow-in-sharepoint-list/

However, when I try the name of the flow simply does not show up anywhere in SharePoint. As such:

My flow (my first trigger is "For a selected element"). Also the flow was created through Sharepoint using the PowerAutomate option.
[image]

Where in SharePoint I would expect an option called "TestTrigger4" to show up (excuse the strange language)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oigel.png)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The answer is that only Power Automate flows from the default solution can be run like this through SharePoint.

Comment: Thank you for your update, you can mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the browser cache, wait for minutes, then re-open the list to compare the result.

Comment: This is an important step aswell